# How to build and apply a custom function for rolling function python?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, rolling-computation

How do I build a custom function to apply to  `df.rolling().apply(func)` that gets the first or last row in the rolling window period and do something with it?

Lets say I have this `df`:

```
Customer #    #1     #2     #3
0             15     42     56    
1             16     36     15    
2             14     69     96    
3             16     89     33    
4             12     98     68
...
1510           9     59     46
```

where the column values are how much each customer is spending over successive days 0-1510. For each rolling window period (lets say 63), how would I be able to get each period's last row and get the proportion of each customer's money spent from the last day of that rolling window period out of all 3 customers so I can calculate the total standard deviation (formula = weights.T * cov_matrix * weights)? I know I can do `df.rolling().mean()` to get mean of spending for that rolling window or `df.rolling().cov()` to generate covariance matrices for each rw, but not sure how to approach getting just the last row to get the weights.